# unable to correctly define edittexts in java

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to define 3 edittexts adjacent to each other in java.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // LinearLayout
    mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    // LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout
    main=new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    main.setLayoutParams(mainParams);
    mainLayout.addView(main);

    // LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout -> EditText1
    EditText item1=new EditText(this);
    item1.setHint("Enter the item");
    item1.setId(5);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    item1.setLayoutParams(etParams);
    main.addView(item1);

    // LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout -> EditText2
    EditText quantity1=new EditText(this);
    item1.setHint("Quantity");
    item1.setId(6);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams qparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, 5);
    item1.setLayoutParams(qparams);
    main.addView(quantity1);

    // LinearLayout -> RelativeLayout -> EditText3
    EditText rate1=new EditText(this);
    item1.setHint("rate");
    item1.setId(7);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, 6);
    item1.setLayoutParams(rparams);
    main.addView(rate1);
```

`

I know you might be thinking that i can also do it in xml but the thing is that i have to create more edittexts at runtime.

The problem is that all the editTexts are overlapping each other. plz help

Comment: It's because you're adding them to RelativeLayout. If you want them to appear one below another, use LinearLayout. And if you define lots of views at runtime, you should consider placing them in some adapter view, ie, ListView

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be because you create `quantity1` and `rate1`, but keep configuring `item1` instance after their creation. Fix the code to configure `quantity1` and `rate1`

Comment: sorry for that mistake. But still they are overlapping

Answer (score 0):

1. **I'm not sure how many `EditTexts` you need, but if it is a relatively small amount, you can show/hide them as you wish in Java.**

   You can use this method to show or hide your `TextView`:

   ```
   yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE); //makes XML element disappear
   yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //makes XML element appear
   ```

   And so in your code, instead of creating a new `EditText`, you can show an existing one, which you have already set a position for.
2. **You should consider using a `LinearLayout` as this may prevent your `TextViews` from being created on top of each other.**